# Characters are being displayed incorrectly in bash

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux, configuration

I've been setting up archlinuxarm installs on my headless raspberry pis and I recently ran into an interesting *problem*. All of the characters `[]\{}|` are being displayed as different characters in my terminal when connecting over SSH. It doesn't prevent anything from working it is just strange to see and annoying that I don't know how to fix it.

Here is what my bash prompt looks like:

`Æuser@host ~Å$` instead of `[user@host ~]$`

And if I were to show the contents of a file containing the character `[` it would instead be displayed as `Æ`.

The problem is not with my terminal as it was working fine before (and still works with other raspberry pis).

I've tried to regenerate the locales, reset the keyboard-layout, but I cannot seem to fix this. I don't even know where to begin searching. I think the change occurred when I accidentally `cat` a large binary file but I don't know what could have happened. I have rebooted several times and compared configs to my other archlinuxarm install and cannot seem to see a difference.

Has anyone experienced this or can anyone offer any advice on what might have caused this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I was going to call it an evening so I started closing terminal. Decided to check one last time by SSHing from my other alarmpi to the weird-character-alarmpi and that apparently did the trick? Not really sure what is going on but it is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary data file probably included some sequences that messed up your terminal. Odd that only those characters changed. Sometimes your whole terminal may be gobledihook. You can issue the `reset` command to clean it up to the initial state.

Or you can open a new terminal window.

Comment: It's not odd at all.  ECMA-35 (ISO/IEC 2022) has hundreds of registered 7-bit character sets, a number of which are simple ECMA-6 (ISO/IEC 646) variants or compatible.  That's probably the Nordisk Avisteknisk Samarbetsnämnd (NATS) character set for Denmark and Norway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations!